# Assign a value to an attribute of a generic method of a generic class - Java

Tags: java, lambda

I need a generic method for assign a value to an attribute of a generic class; I'll do an example to better explain. The method I need I suppose should be something like that:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
public class Utilities {

 public static <T> Object assignValueToAttribute( Object MY_Object__Arg, Function<T, ?> MY_AttributeValueExtractor_Arg, Object MY_AttributeValueToEqual_Arg) {
    return ....
}
```

}

EXAMPLE:

let's say I have a Class called 'Car' with a NOT STATIC method 'setColor()'.
My generic method should return an istance of Car,  let's say 'myCar', and assign the value "red" at the attribute 'color'

```
myCar.setColor("red");
```

My generic method could be invoked with something like that:

```
Car myCar= (Car) Utilities.assignValueToAttribute(myCar, oggetto -> oggetto.setColor(), "red");
```

PROBLEM: I don't know hot to code that method...

Comment: How about using reflection? It would be at least as generic as can be.

Comment: The object are istances of a very simple class, let's say "Car", that will have an attribute color, and a method getColor(), setColor(), an attribute model, and a method getModel(), setModel(), etc...
Then I'll have other simple classes, for example, "Bycicle", that will have an attribute "type", with a method 'setType(9' and 'getType()'.
And so on with other classes...

Comment: I'm not so expert, I didn't understand very much... mayyou write the code, please?

Comment: I'd avoid reflection, it gives problems with Proguard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close.  You need two generic types: a type for your object (bean), and a type for the value.  You want a [BiConsumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html), not a Function, because a set-method does not return anything.

```
public static <T, V> T assignValueToAttribute(T obj, BiConsumer<T, V> attributeSetter, V value) {
    attributeSetter.accept(obj, value);
    return obj;
}
```

You can then invoke it as:

```
assignValueToAttribute(myCar, Car::setColor, "red");
```

Note that re-assigning `myCar` is pointless.  It’s the same object that it was before the method call.